# MDX query for average of sums by month and year

Tags: sql-server, mdx, average

I'm stuck on a MDX query... I have a table which looks like:

```
Date         Client        Amount
---------------------------------
2010-01-01        1          1000
2010-01-01        2           500
2010-01-02        1          1100
       ...      ...           ...
2011-09-30        3          2000
```

Basically, I'd like to have a MDX equivalent of the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], AVG(DailyTotal)
FROM (
    SELECT [Year], [Month], [Day], SUM(Amount) as DailyTotal
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY [Year], [Month], [Day]
)
GROUP BY [Year], [Month]
```

I'm trying to get as result like

```
        Jan    ...   Sept
2010    AVG    ...    AVG
2011    AVG    ...    AVG
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a query using Adventure Works:

```
with member [measures].[Average] as Avg({Descendants([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember, [Date].[Calendar].[Date])*[Date].[Month of Year].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
select 
{{[Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year]}*{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [measures].[Average]}} on columns,
{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]} on rows
From    [Adventure Works]
```

In this query I'm using 2 hierarchies ([Date].[Calendar] and [Date].[Month of Year]). Maybe, in your case, you could need do something else if your time dimension have others hierarchies.

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from 
(
    select [Year], [Month], avg(DailyTotal) as AVERAGE
    from (
            select 
                [Year]              = year([date]), 
                [Month]             = month([date]), 
                [day]                   = day([date]) ,
                [DailyTotal]  = sum([Amount])
            from [Table]
            group by year(date), month(date), day(date)
    ) Q
    group by [Year], [Month]
) K
pivot (max(AVERAGE) for K.[Month] in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) as S
```

Comment: all you need to do is highlight any code and click the `{}` button and your code will be formatted. Ive done it for you in this instance.

Comment: However, for the record, you've posted SQL code. The OP asked for MDX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Jamiec is right, I need the MDX query